# Confusing Inequality

Tags: inequality

[image]

I actually saw this question really straightforward. since $y>x$, the reciprocal of $x$ would be bigger than the reciprocal of $y$, so the answer is A. However, when I checked the memo, it said the answer was D. Please can someone explain to me where I went wrong?

Comment: What if one of them is negative?

Comment: BTW, "I actually saw this question really straightforward." is not a good sentence in English.  Perhaps you want to say "I actually thought this question was really straightforward."

Comment: It's grammatically correct. There's nothing wrong with the sentence.

Comment: No the sentence is not grammatically correct Mathlete. Are you a native English speaker?

Comment: Yes, I am. Since you are so eager to prove me wrong, explain why it is not grammatically correct.

Comment: Perhaps you meant "I actually saw this question *as* really straighforward"?  There's something missing obviously.  You cannot just say "saw this question really straightforward" without something between "question" and "really".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a hint.You forgot about negative numbers.

Consider the case when $x = -1$ and $y = 2$

There's also a chance of $x$ being 0.

Answer (score 1):

What are $1/x$ and $1/y$ for $(x,y)=(1,7)$...?
And what are they for $(x,y)=(-1,7)$...?

And for $(0,1).$..?

Answer (score 1):

Remember: you can't divide by $0$!
The question only states that $x+y>0$. It never stated that one of the two variables couldn't be $0$. Therefore, not enough information is given.